# Matrix rotation, list index out of range

Tags: python

Trying to rotate a matrix of size 3 in counterclockwise direction.

```
def anti(matrix,n):

    while n > 0: # n is the no of rotations 
        l = len(matrix)
        new_matrix = [[row[:] for row in matrix]]
        for i in range(l-1,-1,-1):
            for j in range(l):
                new_matrix[l-i-1][j] = matrix[j][i]
        matrix = [row[:] for row in new_matrix]
        n -= 1
    return matrix
```

The error I got was:

> List index out of range in line 7

Comment: judging by the output you're putting back into the `matrix` variable, `new_matrix` is intialized with too many outer brackets

Comment: @Poojan Suppose for a size 3 matrix, the first value that i will take is (3-1=2) so in new_matrix(l-i-1) line (3-2-1=0) will come up.

Comment: @EshuManohare Yes that's wrong on my part. Can you please remove extra square brackets around here? `new_matrix = [[row[:] for row in matrix]]` and try.

Comment: For n % 4 == 1, you have `return [list(r) for r in zip(*matrix)][::-1]`

Comment: Do not edit your question in a way that it invalidates existing answers etc. Instead, post a **new question**. Read [ask], thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There is extra `[]` in your `new_matrix`. Which is causing dimension miss match between `new_matrix` and `matrix`.

```
def anti(matrix,n):

    while n > 0: # n is the no of rotations 
        l = len(matrix)
        new_matrix = [row[:] for row in matrix]
        for i in range(l-1,-1,-1):
            for j in range(l):
                new_matrix[l-i-1][j] = matrix[j][i]
        matrix = [row[:] for row in new_matrix]
        n -= 1
    return matrix
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

print(anti(a, 3))
```